# Function to find Last Populated Column in LibreOffice Macro

Tags: macros, openoffice, libreoffice

I am trying to find the column Index for last populated column for a specific row and for the same purpose I am trying to write a function in LibreOffice. I must first say that I am a total newbie in macro writing especially LibreOffice since I am coming from Excel background. Though I have tried to write a function with the help from forums I am unable to correct the function for columns fully here is the link to the original function for finding last row:

https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=10817

Help would be appreciated if someone can help me find the error in the function, the problem seems to be with the section of Column Index only.

```
Function LastColumnIndex (InformedRow, Optional InformedSheet) as long
'this function returns the index of the last column with data in a row
'it returns -1 if the whole row is empty
   Dim oSheet As Object, C as Long
   Dim oColumn As Object, oFinder As Object, oResult as object
   Dim PartsOfTheName   

   '------- Sheet -------
   If IsMissing(InformedSheet) then
      oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
   ElseIf IsNumeric(InformedSheet) then
      oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(InformedSheet)
   Else
      oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.GetByName(InformedSheet)
   End If

   '------- Row -------
   If Not IsNumeric(InformedRow) then
      Dim AllRowNames (0 to 1048575)      
      AllRowNames = oSheet.Rows.ElementNames
      For i = 0 to 1048575
         If AllRowNames(i) = UCase(InformedRow) then
            C = i
         End If
      Next
   Else
      C = InformedRow
   End If

   '------- Search -------
   oRow = oSheet.Rows(C)
   oFinder = oRow.createSearchDescriptor
   oFinder.searchRegularExpression = true
   oFinder.SearchString = "."
   oResult = oRow.FindAll(oFinder)

   '------- Column Index -------
   If Not IsNull(oResult) then
      ResultName$ = oResult.AbsoluteName
      PartsOfTheName = Split(ResultName,"$")
      LastColumnIndex = Val(PartsOfTheName(ubound(PartsOfTheName))) - 1
   Else
      LastColumnIndex = - 1
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but the code has a lot of problems.  It looks like you were confused as to whether the code should be about rows or columns, which parts are supposed to be numeric versus named by letter, and how to work with UNO objects.  Have you tried an introspection tool such as [Xray](http://berma.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html)?

Here is a function that works:

```vb
Function LastColumnIndex (InformedRow As Long, Optional InformedSheet) As Long
    'this function returns the index of the last column with data in a row
    'it returns -1 if the whole row is empty
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim oColumn As Object, oFinder As Object, oResult as object
    Dim PartsOfTheName
    Dim LastColumnName As String

    '------- Sheet -------
    If IsMissing(InformedSheet) then
        oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    ElseIf IsNumeric(InformedSheet) then
        oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets(InformedSheet)
    Else
        oSheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.GetByName(InformedSheet)
    End If

   '------- Search -------
   oRow = oSheet.Rows(InformedRow)
   oFinder = oRow.createSearchDescriptor
   oFinder.searchRegularExpression = true
   oFinder.SearchString = "."
   oResult = oRow.FindAll(oFinder)

   '------- Column Index -------
   LastColumnIndex = -1
   If Not IsNull(oResult) then
      ResultName$ = oResult.AbsoluteName
      PartsOfTheName = Split(ResultName,"$")
      LastColumnName = PartsOfTheName(UBound(PartsOfTheName) - 1)
      oColumns = oSheet.getColumns()
      If oColumns.hasByName(LastColumnName) Then
          oColumn = oColumns.getByName(LastColumnName)
          LastColumnIndex = oColumn.getRangeAddress().StartColumn
      End If
   End If
End Function
```

I tested it with this routine:

```vb
Sub LastColumnIndexExample
    MsgBox LastColumnIndex(3, 0)  'row 4 of the first sheet
End Sub
```